# What's the best way to register a function to run during an unexpected exit of a Rust program?

Tags: rust, exit, atexit

I'm creating a terminal text editor in Rust. The editor puts the terminal into raw mode, disabling character echoing and the like, and then restores the original terminal function upon exit.

However, the editor has some bugs, and crashes unexpectedly every now and again due to issues like unsigned variable underflow. When this happens, the cleanup code which would restore the terminal to its original state never runs.

The cleanup function I'd like to run is the following:

```
fn restore_orig_mode(editor_config: &EditorConfig) -> io::Result<()> {
    termios::tcsetattr(STDIN, termios::TCSAFLUSH, &editor_config.orig_termios)
}
```

Comment: You could create a new thread to run your application in. The main application thread would have almost nothing that could go wrong and can clean up and restart the child thread if it panics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html). I haven't used it, so I cannot guarantee it works.

Comment: Not in the same stratosphere of what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Well I think it actually can solve op's problem. What do you think @isaacg

Comment: @Qix Crashes due to "unsigned variable underflow" are due to panic, which `catch_unwind` *does* handle. (The docs warn that this wouldn't catch panics that abort the process, but those wouldn't be caught by the thread approach either.)

Comment: @Qix it's... exactly in the same "stratosphere". Perhaps you could *explain* why you think it's not?

Comment: @for1096 I will say that your answer is pretty sparse. Stack Overflow (and especially here in [tag:rust]) strongly appreciate thorough, in-depth answers. Taking the time to make some example code to prove out your idea (and allowing you to remove the "cannot guarantee") would help a lot.

Comment: On further review, it looks like this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

In the latest stable Rust, @for1096's answer is the best. In your case, it might be quite simple to apply because your clean-up does not need to use state that is shared with the application code:

```
use std::panic::catch_unwind;

fn run_editor(){
    panic!("Error!");
    println!("Running!");
}

fn clean_up(){
    println!("Cleaning up!");
}

fn main(){
    match catch_unwind(|| run_editor()) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Exited successfully"),
        Err(_) =>  clean_up()
    }
}
```

If your clean-up requires accessing shared state with your application, then you will need some additional machinery to convince the compiler that it is safe. For example, if your application looks like this:

```
// The shared state of your application
struct Editor { /* ... */ }

impl Editor {
    fn run(&mut self){
        println!("running!");
        // panic!("Error!");
    }

    fn clean_up(&mut self){
        println!("cleaning up!");
    }

    fn new() -> Editor {
        Editor { }
    }
}
```

Then, in order to call `clean_up`, you would have to manage access to the data, something like this:

```
use std::panic::catch_unwind;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let editor = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Editor::new()));

    match catch_unwind(|| editor.lock().unwrap().run()) {
         Ok(_) => println!("Exited successfully"),
         Err(_) => {
             println!("Application panicked.");
             let mut editor = match editor.lock() {
                Ok(guard) => guard,
                Err(poisoned) => poisoned.into_inner(),
             };
             editor.clean_up();
         }
    }
}
```

Prior to Rust 1.9, you can only handle panics that occur in a child thread. This isn't much different except that you need to clone the `Arc` because the original one will need to be `move`d into the thread closure.

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let editor = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Editor::new()));
    // clone before the original is moved into the thread closure
    let editor_recovery = editor.clone();

    let child = thread::spawn(move || {
         editor.lock().unwrap().run();
    });

    match child.join() {
        Ok(_) => println!("Exited successfully"),
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Application panicked.");
            let mut editor = match editor_recovery.lock() {
                Ok(guard) => guard,
                Err(poisoned) => poisoned.into_inner(),
            };
            editor.clean_up();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of using threads for this sort of thing, as opposed to concurrency. I'm not going to accept for a bit, in case more ideas come in, but I tried this, and it seems to be working really well.

Comment: As the other answer says, [`catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) allows avoiding a thread.

Comment: @Shepmaster Is there a downside to `catch_unwind`? The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html#notes) mentions that it won't work for abortive panics. I don't know how to check if my solution would work there either as I don't know an example of what would cause an abortive panic as opposed to an unwind.

Comment: @PeterHall as [user4815162342 mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441047/whats-the-best-way-to-register-a-function-to-run-during-an-unexpected-exit-of-a/43441583?noredirect=1#comment73940693_43441099), both solutions will fail in the face of [panic=abort](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/07/07/Rust-1.10.html). The good news is that that setting is up to the binary author; since OP is making an editor, presumably they are making a binary and can opt to not set that option. The threaded answer has the benefit of working before Rust 1.9 though.

Answer (score 1):

A common solution to this problem in Unix applications and using other languages such as C is to `fork()` and have your parent wait for the child. On an error exit by the child, clean up.

This is really the only reliable way to clean up if the clean up is important. For example, your program might be killed by the Linux OOM kill. It will never be able to run a language specific panic, exception, at_exit or anything like that because the operating system simply destroys it.

By having a separate process watching it, that process can handle any special cleanup of files or shared memory.

This solution does not really require using `fork()`. The parent could be a shell script or a separate executable.

Comment: A downvote? I shouldn't have said "in C" I guess. Because using a subprocess is really the *only* reliable way to get cleanup.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do get occasional answers where the poster misses the language completely. This isn't such a case, so I've edited a bit to clarify that your solution is language agnostic. However, [like the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441047/whats-the-best-way-to-register-a-function-to-run-during-an-unexpected-exit-of-a/43441583?noredirect=1#comment73942311_43441099), this answer is also pretty sparse. Pointing at the idiomatic Rust code to implement the solution (calling `fork` directly isn't idiomatic) and explaining why it's the "only reliable way" would help a lot.